# Synchronize embedded DB with remote DB

Tags: java, mysql, h2

At the moment, I have a little JavaFX app that generates reports and statistics from the data on a remote MySQL-Server. I use EclipseLink for persistence. Since the access is read-only and the data doesn´t always need to be fresh, I thought I could speed things up by using an embedded DB (H2) that can be synchronized to the remote server when and if the user wishes to. The problem is, I don´t have a clue how to go about it.

What I came up with so far, is to execute mysqldump, make a dump of the remote server and execute the resulting SQL script locally. This is surely far from elegant, so: Is there a patent solution for this task?

Comment: Are we talking about a lot of tables and data (or even possible a lot of data over the time)?

Comment: about 50 tables, about 100MB, but not particularly fast growing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 50 tables possible have a considerable amount of relations, this can be tricky... As far as I know there is nothing that automate this for you or something like that. Very possible that you will have to create your own logic to that. When I did something like what are you trying to do I used the logic of "last update", like, the local data have the timestamp of the time it was last synced with the remote, and the remote data have the timestamp of the last time the data was updated there (himself on the table, or even a relation to it like a One-To-One). Having that data, every time the local user enter a part of the system that can be outdated, the client connect to the server and check if the `last update` timestamp is bigger that the local synced timestamp, if so, it updates the full object and relation. I consumed some time to develop but at the end worked like a charm. There may be some other way to do it, but this was the way I found at the time. Hope it helps you with your problem.